# Getting 2 digits floating number isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have this number : -0.0166667 and I would like to get only two floating digits, so the number should be -0.01

I tried this

```
-0.0166667.toFixed(2)  # gives : -0.02
```

and also this

```
Math.round(-0.0166667 * 100) / 100 # also gives : -0.02
```

But both of them transform the number to -0.02 instead of -0.01

What's wrong here ?

Comment: So you don't want rounding, but truncation?

Comment: Can't get jsPerf to work right now, but I don't see why substring() wouldn't work here if you're just truncating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|` bitwise or for truncate the fraction part.

```js
var x = (-0.0166667 * 100 | 0) / 100,
    y = (0.0166667 * 100 | 0) / 100;
document.write(x + '<br>' + y);
```

A better solution which saves the sign, applies flooring and puts the sign back.

```js
function toFixed(x, digits) {
    return (x < 0 ? - 1 : 1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(x) * Math.pow(10, digits)) / Math.pow(10, digits);
}

document.write(toFixed(-0.0166667, 2) + '<br>');
document.write(toFixed(0.0166667, 2) + '<br>');

document.write(toFixed(-0.0166667, 3) + '<br>');
document.write(toFixed(0.0166667, 3) + '<br>');
```

Comment: The bitwise operation will work, but it potentially loses information.

Comment: Could this be used for 3 precision digits? (curious)

Comment: If Math.sign was supported in ie and safari, the second one would be even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers between less then zero, `Math.ceil` truncates without rounding and for  numbers greater then zero `Math.floor` works fine. As your number is less then zer so use `Math.ceil` instead

`Math.ceil(-0.0166667 * 100) / 100`

**EDIT**

Write a custom helper method to truncate floating point

```
function truncate(num) {
    return num > 0 ? Math.floor(num) : Math.ceil(num);
}
```

and to round number off by 2 digits use

`truncate(num * 100) / 100`

Comment: This will make positive numbers round upwards as well. Truncation is "rounding to zero".

Answer (score 1):

`Math.round` will round the number to the nearest integer, so the output of your code is actually correct. What you need is truncation instead of rounding. Here is the simplest way to do that:

```js
function toZero(x) {
  return x > 0 ? Math.floor(x) : Math.ceil(x);
}

function round2digits(x) {
  return toZero(x * 100) / 100;
}

document.write(round2digits(-0.0166)); // prints `-0.01`
```